# use smtp.mydomain.com to forward to smtp.gmail.com?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I am using google apps for email. I can send email out through c# code fine with smtp.gmail.com.
I would like to be able to use the name smtp.mydomain.com instead, but still have it go to smtp.gmail.com. I tried just seeing a CNAME in my DNS settings, but I get this error:

"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't, the TLS certificate used to communicate privately with the remote SMTP server is signed with smtp.gmail.com. The only solution is to create a SMTP relay with sendmail for example on your own server.